# Change center of map in OpenLayers dynamically

Tags: openlayers-2

Is there a way to change the center of the map in OpenLayers dynamically? For example on button click. It would be too much to ask a "fly to" functionality and as I read this is offered in OpenLayers 3 but currently I am using OpenLayers 2 and we don't plan to migrate.

I tried something as simple as:

```
map.setCenter(22.191969,38.784336,7);
```

but this doesn't work..

Comment: Is there a refresh or redraw option?  Perhaps a zoom-to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`OpenLayers.Map.setCenter`](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.setCenter) has a different signature:

```
setCenter: function(lonlat,
                    zoom,
                    dragging,
                    forceZoomChange)
```

Where `lonlat` is an `OpenLayers.LonLat` object.

You can also use [moveTo](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.moveTo) which has a similar paramaters list.